# exec() function within Laravel works wrong, in tinker and console properly

Tags: laravel, imagemagick

I have a weird problem with exec function within the Laravel app. Using imagemagick library I have to combine two pdf files - the same shell command works properly in terminal, exec() with this command in tinker works properly too. However, when called from job or controller within the Laravel app it looks like it is not seeing the original file at all. What can be the reason? All files are stored in generated storage subfolders.

- works properly in tinker
- works properly in terminal
- works properly in simple test php file outside Laravel app
- does not work in job/controller within the Laravel app (looks like it is not reading the input file_1.pdf (output file is generated with overlay file only, no source "background")
  Already tried Process::class as well, exec used to simplify the code. Permissions are set properly.

```php
exec('convert "/Users/robert/Sites/start-app/storage/documents/file_1.pdf" null: "/Users/robert/Sites/start-app/storage/documents/stamps/1.png" -gravity SouthEast -geometry +150+150 -compose over -layers composite "/Users/robert/Sites/start-app/storage/documents/processed/output_file_1.pdf"');
```

Comment: Does it work if you use the available classes in PHP? https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php

Comment: I have not tested it yet using the wrapper, wanted to make just a simple command-line operation and cannot believe, that the same command in exec() does not behave the same way in tinker, console and from within the Laravel app. I will check it, maybe it helps - thanks for suggestion.

Comment: Does the application have permissions to access the file? When you use the other methods, they all run as you. Laravel will run the command as the account running the web service. So on Ubuntu running apache you would need to check www-data has access to the files.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have different php.ini files for servering web requests and handling cli? These are usually stored in the following (or similar) folders

```
/etc/php/7.3/cli/php.ini
/etc/php/7.3/fpm/php.ini
```

You can also check this by running `phpinfo()` from the cli and also from a web request and compare both.

If that's the case you should check out the `disable_functions` option. More info on that can be found [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-apache-lighttpd-phpini-disable-functions/). Remember to restart your webserver afterwards, so the changes take effect.

Answer (score 0):

I have just finally found the solution. The issue was caused by path to GhostScript, even though imagemagick and gs are in the same path, for some reason when executed from within the app by exec() the gs command could not be found.
Just in case someone faces similar problem, here is the solution:

```php
exec('export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH; convert "/Users/robert/Sites/start-app/storage/documents/file_1.pdf" null: "/Users/robert/Sites/start-app/storage/documents/stamps/1.png" -gravity SouthEast -geometry +150+150 -compose over -layers composite "/Users/robert/Sites/start-app/storage/documents/processed/output_file_1.pdf"');
```

Adding the export path made it working properly.

Answer (score 0):

For people who get to this topic, I would suggest using Laravel's `Process` facade. It has helpful methods to identify the issue you encounter. If your command happens not to work, you can observe the error message as follows:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Process;

$result = Process::run('my failing command --here');

return $result->errorOutput();
```

Btw, the issue is mostly because the users are different, as OP stated. The user executing laravel can have a different `PATH`, or your command may look for a different config location (of the different user) etc.

For further info on `Process`, look at [here](https://laravel.com/docs/processes).